# Wifi works on live cd but not when I boot from hd

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, intel, centrino

I have been installing different variants of Ubuntu over the last couple of days. I have installed linux mint, lubuntu, kubuntu, xubuntu, ES luma. The following behavior is present in all of them.

Wifi works while in live usb, but stops working once I boot from Hard disk. I have no idea why.

I have gone over so many solutions online that I don't know where to start.
**

The following si the resuult of some of the commands that i ran

Output of `sudo rfkill list`

```
waly@waly-Ideapad-Z570:~$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for waly: 
0: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
waly@waly-Ideapad-Z570:~$
```

Output of `sudo ifconfig`

```
waly@waly-Ideapad-Z570:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:a1:84:4d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.106  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f2de:f1ff:fea1:844d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40557 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:57457240 (57.4 MB)  TX bytes:2683630 (2.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:745 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:745 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:68224 (68.2 KB)  TX bytes:68224 (68.2 KB)
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
waly@waly-Ideapad-Z570:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:e5:0b:72:bb:66
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.11.0-15-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:45 memory:f1500000-f1501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: f0:de:f1:a1:84:4d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1404000-f1404fff memory:f1400000-f1403fff

sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
waly@waly-Ideapad-Z570:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
waly@waly-Ideapad-Z570:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   12.879198] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   12.879324] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   13.039566] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 op_mode iwldvm
[   13.169710] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   13.169711] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   13.169712] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   13.169713] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P disabled
[   13.169714] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
[   13.169807] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   13.176934] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   13.246301] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
waly@waly-Ideapad-Z570:~$
```

The following is what I have tried and it doesn't work

- It shows that it is hard blocked but it is not. The button on my
  laptop is to the right, where it should be, and bluetooth is on. I
  toggle it back and forth but it only keeps turning bluetooth on and
  off. I tried it on the Live USB and it was working fine. It was
  turning the wifi on and off.
- I have gone to bios and reset bios to make sure that my laptop would reset the switch, that didn't work

I am ready to do what ever it takes to fix this, but I currently have got no idea what else to do.

Edit:

`lsmod` for harddisk install

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6748161/

Now strangely it is not working in live USB either :S. here is the lsmod (Read Edit2 below)

I tried both ubuntu 13.10 live cd and linux mint 16 cinnamon live usb, they are both now not working.

`sudo rfkill` list shows that it is being hard blocked. I am going crazy now. I am about to give up and load ****ing windows back

In case anyone doubted that the bios has wireless or wifi disabled. Here is a pic

[image]

I need 10 reputation to post images or more than 2 links

Edit2:

OK I installed windows xp and then updated my bios as there was an update for it. I am currently booting ubuntu off a live usb and wifi is working fine. I got the lsmod now.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6764089/

Wish me luck, I am going to install ubuntu and hopefully its gonne work. Keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: Please try: sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop && sudo rfkill unblock all. If the wireless comes to life, we'll tweak a file and make it permanent.

Comment: Just did that, sudo rfkill list still shows it as hard blocked

Comment: is there any option on bios to turn on or off wifi.

Comment: Please run the live CD and run: lsmod. Paste the result here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/  Give us the link in your reply. Then do the same for your harddrive install.

Comment: lsmod for harddisk install http://paste.ubuntu.com/6748161/

Comment: Now strangely it is not working in live USB either :S. here is the lsmod http://paste.ubuntu.com/6748186/

Comment: Loading Windows will not likely solve this, if the LAN is "hard blocked" that means that it is effectively shut off and unavailable to the motherboard....There should be a setting in the BOIS to enable the network or network adapter, allow networking ect. that you will need to change.  Installing any OS to fix the problem at this point would be like changing a light bulb when the switch was shut off and expecting the new light bulb to light up....

Comment: Please try: sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi && sudo rfkill unblock all. How about now? Again, we can tweak one file to make it persistent if it helps.

Comment: it is still showing up as hard blocked when I check rfkill list. TrailRider I am attaching a picture of the bios to show you that it is indeed enabled in bios but it doesn't show up inside ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK just fixed everything. WIFI is finally working :)

This is what I did. There was a bios update available for my laptop. I went ahead and downloaded it. Then I went ahead and installed windows XP as I was not gonne take any chances with a bios update. Plus it did require a GUI to make it work. So I could possibly use FreeDos to update it.

Once the bios was updated. I went ahead and installed ubuntu as I would normally do. And now everything is working fine.

Thanks to anyone that provided their suggestions.