# wifi works when booting from Live CD but not booting from hard disk

Tags: wireless, live-cd

I had 14.10 running fine on my Dell Latitude until Unity flaked out on me. I reinstalled and everything seems fine except that "Enable Wifi" only shows up (and lets me connect to my wifi network) when I boot from the installation CD. When I boot from the hard disk, my wifi network is listed in Edit Connections with all the same settings that are showing when I boot from the CD, but I can't use it.

I think this is different from [Wifi works on live cd but not when I boot from hd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405052/wifi-works-on-live-cd-but-not-when-i-boot-from-hd) because it was all working fine with the same machine, BIOS, and Ubuntu release a week ago and also because I don't get "network DISABLED" when I run sudo lshw -C network.

The lsmod output when booting from the CD is so much longer that I'm guessing that one of those modules is what's making the wifi connection possible. Can anyone tell me which and how to make it part of the hard disk system?

sudo lshw -C network  # after booting from CD and before connecting to wifi

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 5c:26:0a:59:91:32
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:e2e00000-e2e1ffff memory:e2e80000-e2e80fff ioport:4080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:e2d00000-e2d03fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 74:de:2b:b4:5b:18
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.16.0-23-generic firmware=610.812 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

sudo lshw -C network  # after booting from CD and after connecting to wifi

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 5c:26:0a:59:91:32
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:e2e00000-e2e1ffff memory:e2e80000-e2e80fff ioport:4080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:e2d00000-e2d03fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 74:de:2b:b4:5b:18
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.16.0-23-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.0.79 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

sudo lshw -C network  # after booting from hard disk

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 5c:26:0a:59:91:32
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:42 memory:e2e00000-e2e1ffff memory:e2e80000-e2e80fff ioport:4080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e2d00000-e2d03fff
```

lsmod when booting from hard disk:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
psmouse               106593  0 
ahci                   34062  2 
sdhci_pci              23301  0 
e1000e                230184  0 
libahci                32424  1 ahci
sdhci                  43448  1 sdhci_pci
ptp                    19445  1 e1000e
pps_core               19333  1 ptp
```

lsmod when booting from CD:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
arc4                   12608  2 
brcmsmac              571212  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15579  1 brcmsmac
b43                   400218  0 
mac80211              660592  2 b43,brcmsmac
intel_rapl             18783  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       18786  0 
dm_crypt               23172  0 
coretemp               13441  0 
kvm_intel             143514  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47547  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      63632  1 
cfg80211              510218  3 b43,brcmsmac,mac80211
snd_hda_codec_generic    68914  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
kvm                   455570  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_intel          30379  3 
snd_hda_controller     35152  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139675  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0 
snd_pcm               104102  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
dell_laptop            18227  0 
dell_wmi               12761  0 
crc32_pclmul           13133  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
ssb                    62366  1 b43
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
aesni_intel           152552  0 
joydev                 17344  0 
dm_multipath           22843  0 
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13287  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
scsi_dh                14882  1 dm_multipath
glue_helper            13944  1 aesni_intel
bnep                   19543  2 
btusb                  32448  0 
serio_raw              13434  0 
snd_seq                67224  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 19742  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
bcma                   52443  3 b43,brcmsmac
lpc_ich                21093  0 
rfcomm                 69509  8 
cryptd                 20360  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
mei                    87931  1 mei_me
snd_timer              29513  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
bluetooth             446190  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd                    87611  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
shpchp                 37040  0 
dell_smo8800           13154  0 
parport_pc             32741  0 
soundcore              15052  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
ppdev                  17671  0 
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
mac_hid                13227  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
squashfs               48362  1 
overlayfs              27917  1 
nls_utf8               12557  1 
isofs                  39837  1 
dm_mirror              22040  0 
dm_region_hash         20850  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18411  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
i915                  917618  3 
i2c_algo_bit           13406  1 i915
drm_kms_helper         61627  1 i915
psmouse               106548  0 
sdhci_pci              23261  0 
ahci                   34062  1 
libahci                32424  1 ahci
e1000e                230184  0 
sdhci                  43448  1 sdhci_pci
drm                   310919  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
ptp                    19445  1 e1000e
pps_core               19333  1 ptp
wmi                    19193  1 dell_wmi
video                  20128  1 i915
```

The following gives me the same output whether booting from CD and from hard disk

lspci -nnk | grep 14e4

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

One other note: when I connect it directly to the router with a cable, it's on the internet just fine.

No output from rfkill list all.

I did a purge bcmwl-kernel-source, update, and new install as described at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110. I did see this when I did the update:

```
DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/modules.dep.bin'
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
```

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Whats rfkill saying ?

Comment: Show the results from `lspci -nnk | grep 14e4` in terminal in your question

Comment: I've added the lspci results above.

I've never used rfkill before and it looks like it needs some parameters. What should I put?

Comment: I think they just wanted to see the result of `rfkill list all` in terminal

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install linux-firmware `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware` and possibly remove a couple modules, Check the post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110 under Special Case #1 for more details

If it works, thank Chili555

Comment: As a 14e4:4727, I guess I'm special case #1, but after installing linux-firmware, it still didn't work with both b43 and ssb in blacklist.conf, with just b43 (because "In some cases, blacklisting ssb will disable your Broadcom ethernet card"), or with neither in there.

When you say "possibly remove a couple modules," can you tell me which?

Comment: Did you reboot after adding the modules to the blacklist?  The modules usually are b43 and/or ssb

Comment: I have rebooted after each suggested change. I originally tried blacklisting both b43 and ssb, then just b43, and now just ssb, but I still get "Disconnected - your are now offline Network" on the login screen, and then after I log in "Enable wifi" is not on the menu.

Comment: You didn't install the broadcom sta driver from the driver manager? bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Because http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110  listed 14e4:4727 as a special case instead of showing the driver name, I had not, so just now I did the purge, update, and install of  bcmwl-kernel-source, and the wifi still doesn't work with both b43 and ssb in blacklist.conf or either alone (rebooting each time). I added additional information above about a message I got during the update that may or may not be relevant.

Comment: After an system update last night, the wifi works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having the same problem with my laptop , and was going mad at me for reinstalling ubuntu . I tried every solution that has " WIFI " in it . But after a long time , i just ran into a page which mentions the difference between `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` . So i tried it out . Voila ! My Wifi is miraculously back after a reboot . So for new linux users like me who have installed an outdated copy of ubuntu . First do the following before proceeding to other solutions .

```
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Hope this helps ! Hope i wont get downvotes for such a simple answer .